# Option text color is white in IE/Edge

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, html-select

I have styled my select a bit, having the text color white. On all browsers except IE/Edge, it displays the selected option as white, and when I open the option list, all the options are black.

In IE/Edge, the option list is also white, so the options are unreadable. The text is only visible on hover.

Using the following CSS didn't help unfortunately:

```
select option {
    color: #000 !important;
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fvevjfg5/

Comment: can you create a fiddle or so?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/fvevjfg5/

Comment: IE & Edge must die soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this `meta` tag in your `head`, That would fix your problem.

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=edge" />
</head>
```

Comment: What I noticed in your fiddle is the text and background are white. That's what the actual problem is. check this https://jsfiddle.net/fvevjfg5/2/. I just changed `background:rgba(255,255,255,0.2);` to `background:rgba(0,0,0,0.8);` and that works fine in IE11 without adding any meta tags. Check from your side :)